# bnlearn, hill-climbing algorithm: how can I get alternative structures in the order of score?

Tags: r, bnlearn

In the R package of "bnlearn", the function "hc" only derives the most plausible structure in a score (e.g., bic, aic).
But, I want to know alternative structures in the order of plausibility (i.e., score).
For example, when three nodes were given (A, B, C), "hc" tells that the best structure is "A->B<-C". 
Then, can I know the second best structure?
I know that by using "set.arc", I can calculate the score of an alternative structure.
But, still, I cannot know the ranking of the alternative structure. 
How can I know alternative structures in the order of score?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I suppose you could trace the search using `debug` : `hc(..., debug=TRUE)`, or maybe see how many iterations the search takes and then rerun setting the `max.iter` to one less??

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by calculating BIC for all possible structures.